# Why is the following variable a mixed random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, bivariate-distributions

Let X∼N(0,1) and W∼Bernoulli(1/2) be independent random variables. Define the random variable Y as a function of X and W:

[image]

Find the PDF of Y and X+Y.

[image]

I don't understand why Z turned out to be a mixed RV. If it can take on a value of 0 with a probability of 0.5, can't we assume 0 itself is ∼N(0,0) instead of a step function?

Comment: I'm going to edit this to put the images inline, but could you please use latex format as far as possible. It is for the benefit of searchers in the future with a similar question. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! My first question here but I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: The cited images don't contain the definition of $\ Z\ $.  Presumably, $\ Z=X-Y=2XW\ $.  And and the cumulative distribution function of a random variable with *zero* variance—whether or not it's normal— *is* a step function.

Comment: We define Z = X + Y which is the second PDF we have to find.

Comment: $Z$ is defined in the bottom image. I don't understand what the questioner is asking either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly think of the degenerate random variable at $0$ as having distribution $N(0, 0)$, but it does not change the fact that $\mathsf{Z}$ is a mixed random variable.
What makes $\mathsf{Z}$ a mixed random variable, is the fact that its distribution is one of two different distributions, depending on $\mathsf{W}$.
Even if $(\mathsf{Z}\mid\mathsf{W}=1)\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for some $\sigma>0$ (and assuming $(\mu, \sigma)\neq(0, 2)$), $\mathsf{Z}$ would *still* be a mixed random variable, even though its distribution given $\mathsf{W}$ is normal either way.

Comment: Yeah I figured that it's a mixed rv that has continuous and discrete parts with an either or 1/2 probability. Thanks for your answer!